# Implication of slant asymptote definition

Tags: calculus

When calculating a slant asymptote, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is used to find the slope of the line.

Does it necessarily mean that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist implies function has a slant asymptote as x goes to infinity or existence of slant asymptote implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$  exist?

Comment: Without defining slant asymptote, who knows? I would guess slant asymptotes are defined precisely by this limit, so that the existence of one is the existence of the other

Comment: @FShrike by defining the slant asymptote, you mean the formal definition or exact slant asymptote of some function?

Comment: If you have a [slant asymtote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Oblique_asymptotes) then the limit exists. The converse is false